# Blender won't detect GPUs (GTX 690 MultiGPU) after a crash

Tags: gpu

When I was rendering in Blender 2.77 with many hair particles, the screen went black and recovered only to display this message:
[image: CrashInfo]

Since this, whenever I go to cycles renderer, I see that it doesn't find my GPUs. I went to RE-ADD both GPUs in user preferences and there's no CUDA option.
[image]

I do have the latest Nvidia drivers installed and this option existed before which worked fine up until the crash. I have tried restarting (lol) and reinstalling the same version with no luck.
Any help with this?

Comment: Did you try rebooting? Re-install the drivers for the GPUs

Comment: @cegaton " I have tried restarting (lol) and reinstalling the same version with no luck."                                                                                                I have tried rebooting but I will Re-Install my drivers now.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it appears to be a bug report, and thus, out of scope of the site.

Comment: One thing you could check is if the cards are operating in sli mode for some reason. They should not for cycles.

Comment: @aliasguru I disabled SLI mode on my card and restarted blender but to no avail. Thank you for helping though.

Comment: @brasshat
Thanks, I just went to check on how to report a bug to blender and I found this : "We can only support the Blender binaries as have been distributed on blender.org. First thing to test is therefore always if official releases have the error. And if there's an error, test it with at least one older official release to verify. This can reveil problems with your graphics drivers for example, it's not likely that big errors are there for many releases!"     -- - - -- - -  So i'll give this a shot to revert any problems.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work either.